# webdriver findElement throws NoSuchElementException even though its inside try/catch

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have a problem with this method throwing NoSuchElementException when the driver can't find the element "error-row". I use this method in two cases. One where it should return true, and one it should return false. Does someone se why it is throwing exception?

```
public boolean isErrorMessagePresent() {
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.className("error-row"));
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I was pointing the NoSuchElementException to the java.util library. Changed to this: *catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e)* and it worked!

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/13990825/2504101. Looks like you are catching `NoSuchElementException` from another namespace. For example this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html

Comment: I think you have import wrong "NoSuchElementException" class in your class . Make sure "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException" you imported this package

Comment: Hi and thanks! This was indeed the problem :) Updated with answer